# Get users from 7.2 - throwing error in Sitecore PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions, user-management

I am using `7.2 Sitecore version`. There I need to fetch users using `PowerShell` script.
I have tried multiple combinations or filters to run for instance -

```
Get-User -Filter *
```

I get an error saying - `item key already been added`. This is happening due to a specific user. It might be more than one users corrupted. I am not even able to access the user through user User Manager.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to access it though membership class. Example to grab all extranet users below.

```
    [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GetAllUsers() | Where-Object {$_.UserName.StartsWith("extranet")} |
Show-ListView -Property @{Name = 'FullName'; Expression = {(Get-User -Identity $_.UserName).Profile.FullName}}, 
    @{Name="User Name"; Expression={ $_.UserName} },
    @{Name="Email"; Expression={ $_.Email} },
    @{Name="Is Enabled"; Expression={ $_.IsApproved} },
    @{Name="Is Locked"; Expression={ $_.IsLockedOut } },
    @{Name="Created Date"; Expression={ $_.CreationDate} },
    @{Name="Last Login Date"; Expression={ $_.LastLoginDate} }
```

I would probably directly access database and try to figure out if there are corrupted users or duplicates.